# Is it legal for 1 color-attachment to map to 2 different input-attachments from 2 different passes?

Tags: vulkan

Is this RenderPass setup legal in Vulkan?

[image: Frame diagram of 4 passes]

That shows a frame setup of 4 subpasses, back to back. Subpass0 (C) outputs to 2 color-attachments. Its second output `C.out1` maps to 2 input attachments: `T0.in1` and `T1.in1`

Is it legal for 1 color-attachment to map to 2 input-attachments from 2 different subpasses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> maps to 2 input attachments: T0.in1 and T1.in1

Subpasses do not own attachments; the render pass owns attachments. Subpasses *use* attachments. The two subpasses are just using the same attachment as input attachments.

It's no different from two drawing commands using the same texture.